# Secret key Error even after setting up in flask

Tags: python, flask

I see below error even after setting  secret_key, unable to figure out what i'm missing here please advice

**Error:**

```
RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

**Code below**

config.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
#from .models import db


db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['secret_key'] = '\x90vv\xdd\x11?<\xbf \xd3\xb2\xab\x12\xb5\xa3\xee'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/WebApp'
    db.init_app(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .models import Person

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return Person.query.get(int(user_id))

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    return app
```

Comment: Try `SECRET_KEY` instead of `secret_key`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of setting a secret key for Flask application.

Using `app.config`, the `SECRET_KEY` part must be uppercase here which is why you're receving an error:

```py
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'my-secret-key'
```

Using Flask application object:

```py
app.secret_key = 'my-secret-key'
```

More information can be found in Flask documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.secret_key

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed the case sensitive part of it.